# Check url for particular string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, url, parameters

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var loc = window.location.hostname;
    alert(loc);

   if (loc = "xyzvalue.com") {
   //do some operation
   }

});
```

I am using above jquery to get current url in jquery.Alert will show xyzvalue.com as popup. Now I want to check for "value" string in xyzvalue.com.

Comment: You mean if you are in "xyzvalue.com", you want look for the attribute "value" on all DOM elements? Or just the plain string "value"?

Comment: Actually you use plain JavaScript to get the host name. jQuery is not involved in this.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (loc = "xyzvalue.com") {
```

should be

```
if (loc == "xyzvalue.com") {
```